# Парсинг данных из angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Заранее извиняюсь за возможно банальный и туповатый вопрос - никогда прежде не имел ничего общего с angular.

---

Исходные данные - есть веб телеграма, написанный на angular, список переписок слева и свое расширение для браузера, которое как раз надо дописать.

---

Задача - добавить по селектору фотографии кнопку свою каждому контакту, причем эта кнопка должна знать id или какой-то другой идентификатор пользователя. И тут наступает проблема - 
Как вот из такого:

```
<i class="icon icon-select-tick" ng-class="{dialog_selected: isSelected(dialogMessage.peerString)}" ng-mousedown="dialogMultiSelect(dialogMessage.peerString, $event)"></i>
```

Достать значение dialogMessage?

Comment: Достать куда? У вас в контроллере dialogMessage должен быть доступен. Из контроллера вы можете его передать в нужный сервис или директиву.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/download + https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=loiane.angular-extension-pack

Comment: Там код минифицирован, исходного доступа у меня нет, говорю же - это web.telegram.org.